# Is it possible to use GM_xmlhttpRequest to my data form using greasemonkey/tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4, gm-xmlhttprequest

I am currently working on GM_getvalue but it only saves data on the local storage.
I wanted to save the inputted values to my server where send.php is located.

This is my code:

```
var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery;

$(document).ready(function() {

    if($("#save_form").html()){
        $("#save_form").submit(function(){
            var fullname = $("#name").val();
            var IDnumber = $("#id").val();
            GM_setValue("attendancelogs",GM_getValue("attendancelogs","")+fullname+" "+IDnumber+"<br/>");
        });
    }
```

Someone suggested me to use GM_xmlhttpRequest but i have no idea how to use it.
He told me GM_xmlhttpRequest looks like this:

```
jQ(document).on("keyup", "form input", function () {
    let value = GM_getValue("name_full","");
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://....",
        data: value,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        onload: function(response) {
            alert(response);
            var json = $.parseJSON(response); 
        }
    });
```

And lastly, what would be the send.php code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GM_xmlHttpRequest` is just an implementation of [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) that can bypass [SOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

You can find the documentation for [XHR in general](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), or [some examples](https://javascript.info/xmlhttprequest).

You will of course need to add the following to your script header:

`// @grant        GM.xmlHttpRequest`